# Effective Property Checks in Dynamically Generated Angular Components

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm generating Angular components on the fly, and the specific component can vary. I need to check if a certain property is present on these dynamically created Angular components. Unfortunately, using JavaScript's 'hasOwnProperty' or the 'in' operator doesn't seem effective for Angular components, as demonstrated by the provided code and StackBlitz example.

My current workaround involves always initialising the properties on the components that are created and checking for 'undefined', but I'm not a fan of this approach. Is there a more effective solution?

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-starter-13-v32dbj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `
    <p>{{ text }}</p>
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
  `
})
export class TestComponent {
  text: string;
  title: string;
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <p>App component</p>
    <ng-template #componentContainer></ng-template>
`,
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('componentContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) componentContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const testComponent: TestComponent = this.componentContainer.createComponent(TestComponent).instance;
    testComponent.text = 'text';
    if (testComponent.hasOwnProperty('title')) {
      testComponent.title = 'title';
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    } else {
      if ('title' in testComponent) {
        testComponent.title = 'title';
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      }
    }
  }
}
```